# Path matching with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, path

I'm having a hard time trying to figure a regex to match patterns of the form:
 path/to/file.html
but reject patterns of the form
  path/to/_file.html

Thx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

`/(?!.*/)[^_].+\.html$`

I've made a couple of assumptions however:

- You can have anything in the path and to section (including underscore)
- You only want to reject underscore in the file section
- The file always ends in HTML

If any of these are wrong please comment and I'll modify appropriately.

Comment: My fault, I didn't specify it, but the number of sections in the path is not known.

Comment: The regex above matches string of the form: /path/to/.../_file.html

Comment: No problem at all @arnaud - do yourself a favour and grab yourself a copy of [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)